# Difference between Wigner function in coherent space and coordinate space

Tags: quantum-optics, coherent-states

Such a density operator $\hat{\rho}$ match with a Wigner function in coherent space: $$W(\alpha,\alpha^{*})$$
$\alpha$ and $\alpha^{*}$ are $C-number$ ( $\alpha^{*}$ denotes complex conjugate of $\alpha$) corresponding to annihilation and creation operator $a$ and $a^\dagger$.

Or we may write Wigner function under coordinate space：
$$W(x,p)$$
where $x$ and $p$ are also $C-number$ corresponding to position and momentum operator $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$.

My question is, if I have a Wigner function under coordinate space $W(x,p)$, may I obtain $W(\alpha,\alpha^{*})$ just simply get through:
$$\alpha→x+p$$
$$\alpha^*→x-p$$
or vice versa:
$$x=(\alpha+\alpha^{*})/2$$
$$p=(\alpha-\alpha^{*})/2i$$
Is there such a simple relationship between them?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_phase_space#Important_result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it suffices to do what you did. And generally if you want to include non-natural units or where everything isn't set to 1;

$$x=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}(\alpha^* + \alpha),\, p=i\sqrt{\frac{\hbar m\omega}{2}}(\alpha^* - \alpha). $$

On a side note, the coherent representation is sometimes more useful because for example in circuit QED or cavity QED,  since $|\alpha|^2$ is the average number of photons - this is immediately more useful since they can control "how many photons" to pump and explore or probe phase space experimentally.